# Gstreamer over UDP between two RIoT boards with CAM8200-U

Tags: linux, video, camera, stream, gstreamer

I am trying to use `gst-launch` to capture a video, stream and save it on a second board. Then I want to verify that the stream was good by playing the video file on a PC.

`CAM8200-U -> RIoT_1------Stream_Ethernet-----RIoT_2 - Save file on RIoT_2.`

Both boards are running `Linux Yocto v3.10.17`

Firstly, I followed this tutorial (I am using `gst-launch-0.10` not `1.0`, because that's the version on the boards): [http://www.z25.org/static/*rd*/videostreaming_intro_plab/](http://www.z25.org/static/_rd_/videostreaming_intro_plab/)

Sender:

`gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5200`

Receiver:

`gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink`

This example works perfectly on the boards! Not really using the camera, but still a good starting point. However, if I change the `autovideosink` with `filesink location=xxx.format (.mp4 .mkv .avi)` the file is not playable.

**Question 1: Do you know how to save this stream in a file that can be played later?**

After searching a bit I was able to stream and save `videotestsrc` with these lines:

Sender:

`gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc !  udpsink host=192.168.1.103 port=5200`

Receiver:

`gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5200 ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! avimux ! filesink location=/home/root/movie.avi`

However, changing the `videotestsrc` with `v4l2src device=/dev/video0` gives me an empty file.

**Question 2: Do you have any ideas why it works with the `videotestsrc` and not with the camera?**

Then I found this example given by element14 on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRbckLppmKs with which I can get video from the camera and save it. This is the line:

`gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=-1 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=1024,height=768' ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! vpuenc codec=0 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=output.mkv sync=false`

I have tried multiple ways of working out this line to stream and save it on the other end, but they were all unsuccessful.

**Question 3: Do you know a proper way I can stream and save video from this camera?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of my question and reply to Matilda:

Thanks, Matilda! Actually it is always on video0 for some reason. My main issue was with getting the stream to work or in very details how to encrypt/decrypt/use the right caps, so it works.

I was able to do streaming and saving from RIoT to RIoT with the following options:

Sender:

`gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=1024,height=768' ! ffmpegcolorspace ! vpuenc codec=5 ! rtph263pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.104 port=5200`

Receiver:

`gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, payload=96 ! rtph263depay ! vpudec ! matroskamux ! filesink location=video3.mkv`

Quite strange was that if I use `avimux` instead of `matroskamux` the video plays back on 5x speed. No idea why, but it doesn't matter at this point. Moreover, these options will not work from a RIoTboard to a PC, just because there is no `vpudec` option in Ubuntu (or at least don't how to add it). Maybe using different way to decrypt the H.263 will work.

Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Additional info:

To stream H.264 with short delay (~200ms)

Sender::::

`gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480' ! ffmpegcolorspace ! vpuenc codec=6 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.103 port=5200 --gst-debug=2`
   


Receiver::::

`gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, payload=96, encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! vpudec low-latency=true ! autovideosink --gst-debug=2`

Answer (score 0):

To capture camera with v4l2src, you must provide correct device for it.
You probably use wrong device here. CAM8200-U is a USB camera, so it is unlikely to be **/dev/video0**

For a USB camera, easiest way to know its device is unplug and re-plug it. The newly appear (usually the last one) video device is device of your camera. Assume the device is */dev/video10*, you command to record file is

*gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src **device=/dev/video10** num-buffers=-1 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,**width=1024,height=768**' ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! vpuenc codec=0 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=output.mkv*

(Remember to check camera manual to confirm **whether resolution 1024x768 is supported**)

And command to send stream is

`gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video10 num-buffers=-1 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=1024,height=768' ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc !  udpsink host=192.168.1.103 port=5200`